# Algolia - format highlighted text to show only highlighted part

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, algolia

I have some attributes indexed in Algolia which contain thousands of letters as value, so the search result appears so big, I can truncate the result based on some max allowed length but it can hide the highlighted  tags.

Is their some option like in google search it only shows part of the text which matches and not the complete text, and part of the text contains highlighted text from multiple regions in the text.

Is this feature available in Algolia or I need to parse the result myself to achieve this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

It was pretty simple just had to add

```
attributesToSnippet
```

property to get the proper snippets